# Analytics is disabled. Event not logged

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I rencently integrated Firebase into my iOS project but I'm having trouble logging events. The automatic screen recording works fine (ViewControllers are shown in the console), but I am not able to manually log events:

```
Analytics.logEvent("test", parameters: nil)
```

I am getting the following message in the debugging console:

> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023049] Analytics is disabled. Event not logged

My .plist file comes straight from Firebase (without modifications) and the Firebase configuration reports the following:

> 2019-01-02 10:18:02.532838+0100 CLCarRental[90575:9644609] 5.12.0 -
>   [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.50300000 started
>   CLCarRental[90575:9644609] 5.12.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023009]
>   Debug logging enabled 2019-01-02 10:18:02.535368+0100
>   CLCarRental[90575:9644609] 5.12.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023013]
>   **Analytics disabled** 2019-01-02 10:18:02.537685+0100
>   CLCarRental[90575:9644393] Reachability Flag Status: -R -------
>   networkStatusForFlags 2019-01-02 10:18:02.624924+0100
>   CLCarRental[90575:9644606] [Answers] Answers enabled with settings:
>
> ```
> {
> "flush_interval_secs" = 300;
> "flush_on_background" = 1;
> "forward_to_google_analytics" = 0;
> "include_purchase_events_in_forwarded_events" = 0;
> "max_byte_size_per_file" = 8000;
> "max_file_count_per_send" = 1;
> "max_pending_send_file_count" = 100;
> "sampling_rate" = 1;
> "track_custom_events" = 1;
> "track_predefined_events" = 1;
> "track_view_controllers" = 0;
> url = "https://e.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/events"; }
> ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the origin of the problem. I had to set the following command in Xcode (after calling `Firebase.configure()`):

```
AnalyticsConfiguration.shared().setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true)
```

Update from @Jeremy when using the newer SDK:

```
Analytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true)
```

Comment: The latest version of the SDK uses this line `Analytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true)`

Comment: For the Objective-C users: 
    [FIRAnalytics setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled:YES]

Answer (score 4):

Add those lines to your Info.plist

```
<key>FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_DEACTIVATED</key>
<string>NO</string>
<key>FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED</key>
<string>YES</string>
```

Comment: Worked for me with an Ionic project